# How safely would random guards guard a watch tower?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

I have come across the following probability problem in my research. To avoid going into unnecessary background, I will present it under a different guise, but the mathematics is the same.

I'm fairly sure that this must be a well-studied problem, but unfortunately I lack the necessary background to search for the relevant literature. Any pointers will be appreciated.

There is a watch tower, ideally to be manned $24$ hours a day. There are $6$ guards willing to volunteer, with each guard $k\in\{1,\dots,6\}$ willing to contribute $k$ *contiguous* hours every $24$.

If these guards make random choices*, independently of each other, as to which time slot they will take, then the worst case scenario is that the watch tower is manned for only $6$ hours a day, and the best case scenario is that it is manned for $6+5+\dots+1=21$ hours a day. But what is the *expected* period for which there will be at least one guard at the tower?

Of course, I am really interested in the general case where the circle is divided into $N$ segments, and there are $K$ contiguous slots of lengths $1,\dots,K$.

---

*In my actual scenario, the guards would show up (and therefore also leave) on the hour, but I don't mind if they are approximated to show up at any time chosen continuously between $0$ and $24$.

Comment: What do you mean by *contiguous*?

Comment: @5xum I would assume no smoke breaks.

Comment: Continguous means in a row, connected.  So guard 2 can't do an hour in the morning and an hour after lunch.

Comment: @5xum "Contiguous" means "in sequence". So guard 4 will show up for 4 hours every 24 in one block, e.g. from 1 pm until 5 pm, every day. These 4 will not be split, eg. from 1 pm until 3 pm and then from 8 pm until 10 pm.

Comment: Can the guards start at any time, or only on the hours?

Comment: @MGA and do I understand correctly that the first guard always only guards for *one* hour? He just randomly decides which hour to pick?

Comment: @DrXorile I don't mind making the problem continuous if it makes the analysis simpler.

Comment: Is it the same time every day?

Comment: Don't worry about the analysis - what do you want?

Comment: @5xum Yes, guard $k$ will always do exactly $k$ hours every day, at the same time.

Comment: @DrXorile On the hour would match my actual scenario more closely. Yes, it is the same time every day.

Comment: Presumably they are equally likely to select any hour, rather than all preferring office hours or something

Comment: @DrXorile Yes, the time slots are chosen randomly with uniform distribution. Sorry for not making that more specific - I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chance that a given hour is not manned is $\frac {18}{24}\cdot \frac {19}{24}\cdot \frac {20}{24}\cdot \frac {21}{24}\cdot \frac {22}{24}\cdot \frac {23}{24}\approx 0.38,$ so the expected number of unmanned hours is about $9.2$